# How to query on indexes between two dates in ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have index names with `myindex-YYYY.MM.dd` pattern.

Lets say I want to query on indexes between the dates `2017.03.10` and `2018.01.25`.

Date math functionality is not enough to get this task done. I could generate the index names between these dates but my request would be too long. And maybe in some cases it will exceed maximum length of `GET` request.

Is there any way to achieve this task without generating index names?

Comment: You can run range query on the dates, why is it not enough?

Comment: Why have you split the index by dates? Can't one index hold the data for all your dates with the date being a field in the document itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot as index names are nit threated as data, thus you cannot use filters on index names per se. You can however narrow down your query using wildcards eg 2017.03.* would give you all idexes from march, and query filters will have to include more fine date criterions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in all the indexes a date field with the same semantics of the index name, if it is not already present. Then you can simply use a range query on that date field to filter the ranges of interest, querying on a alias like myindex* :

```
GET my_alias/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "timestamp" : {
                "gte": "start_date", 
                "lte": "end_date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```